# Ruby on Rails Ajax Checkbox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery

How can I bind a click event to a column of checkboxes in a table?

```
- @foos.each do |foo|
  = check_box_tag 'checkbox', foo.active, foo.active

:javascript 
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $this = document.getElementById('active');
  if($this.checked == true){
    $this.bind("click", function(){ alert("True");});
  } else if (document.getElementById('active').checked == false) {
    $this.bind("click", function(){ alert("False");});
  }
});
```

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: I did not test. My code was working... Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had a wrong selector for jQuery, use this:

```
:javascript 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
      $(this).bind("click", function(){ alert($(this).is(":checked")); });
    });      
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("input:checkbox[name=checkbox]").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.bind("click", function(){ alert($this.is(":checked")); });
  });
```